# Fast database for JavaScript data visualization vs minifying CSV?

Tags: javascript, database, csv, data-visualization

I have a 10 MB CSV file that is the fundamental data source for an interactive JavaScript visualization.

In the GUI, the user will typically make a selection of Geography, Gender, Year and Indicator.
The response is an array of 30 4-digit numbers.

I want the user experience to be as snappy as possible and am either considering delivering the full CSV file (compressed using various means ...) or having a backend service that almost matches locally hosted data.

What are my options and what steps can I take to deliver the query response with maximum speed?

Comment: A 10-megabyte download wouldn't be too friendly to your mobile users.

Comment: Personally, I'd host the CSV file and have your server side parse out the data and make an AJAX call to it. If you're concerned about speed, I'd consider getting rid of the CSV in favor of a database (I don't know your constraints, though).

Answer (score 0):

To deliver the full file maybe a combination of String Compression algorithmns such as http://code.google.com/p/jslzjb/ combined with html5 web storage.

However if its not really necessary to have the full db at the users client (which might lead into further problems regarding db updates, security, etc.) i would use a backend service with query caching etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't transfer it to the client,  Who knows how fast their connection is?  Maximum speed would be to create an api, and query it from your mobile client.  This would only mean a request for data is transfered from the client (small in size) and a response is returned to the client (only 30 4 digit number)

Comment: could you actually check whether the connection rate is sufficient enough to deliver full size or not and fall back to the backend solution?

Comment: @mightyuhu what advatage does having the db on the client end provide? how many times will they be querying it? I just think you should weigh the pros and cons of transfering a huge 10mb file to the client if they only need to query it a couple times per use.  Will they redownload it ever time the program starts?  What happens if the db gets stale data?  Perhaps you should make a native app and include it as sqlite db?  I think there are many options but transfering 10mb database is one of the least desirable?